# Should I implement async Parallel or async Task

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await, class-library

***All of this code is in a class library at the lowest level.***

For the code block below should I wrap the entire body of code in a `Task.Run(()=>{});` or is there a better way to fire each one of those `.GroupParts` ? Is there where async Parallel would come into play?

```
    public IGroupedParts GroupParts(GroupOption option)
    {
        IGroupedParts gParts = new GroupedParts();

        if (this.Doors.Count > 0) { gParts.Doors = this.Doors.GroupParts(option); }

        if (this.Leafs.Count > 0) { gParts.Leafs = this.Leafs.GroupParts(option); }

        if (this.Sidelites.Count > 0) { gParts.Sidelites = this.Sidelites.GroupParts(option); }

        if (this.Glass.Count > 0) { gParts.Glass = this.Glass.GroupParts(option); }

        if (this.GlassStops.Count > 0) { gParts.GlassStops = this.GlassStops.GroupParts(option); }

        if (this.Horizontals.Count > 0) { gParts.Horizontals =this.Horizontals.GroupParts(option); }

        if (this.Verticals.Count > 0) { gParts.Verticals = this.Verticals.GroupParts(option); }

        if (this.Sills.Count > 0) { gParts.Sills = this.Sills.GroupParts(option); }

        if (this.Midrails.Count > 0) { gParts.Midrails = this.Midrails.GroupParts(option); }

 ...///still more code but omitted

        return gParts;
    }
```

---Here is an example of what I am talking about when I say wrap the entire body of code with the `Task.Run(()=>{});`

```
public async Task<IGroupedParts> GroupParts(GroupOption option)
        {
            return await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    IGroupedParts gParts = new GroupedParts();

                    if (this.Doors.Count > 0) { gParts.Doors = this.Doors.GroupParts(option); }

                    if (this.Leafs.Count > 0) { gParts.Leafs = this.Leafs.GroupParts(option); }

                    if (this.Sidelites.Count > 0) { gParts.Sidelites = this.Sidelites.GroupParts(option); }

                    return gParts;
                });
        }
```

**---I do not have a Parallel example that is why I am asking for help...**

Comment: What's your platform, and how long does each one (usually) take?

Comment: Each: 00:00:00.0100005

All:  00:00:00.0140008

This is for one page that would go into a set of Blueprints.

The thing about it is that this is that the entire set of pages that go into one roll of drawings could be 15 - 50 pages.

Also, this is all the info needed to draw each page, which each page is a Bitmap, so I'm just looking to trim anywhere i can.

Comment: Currently this is not on a server platform, and this library will have it's own server that is beefed up.

Comment: Do you expect a lot of concurrent usage on your server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are currently wrapping the entire operation seems fine to me. However, it is not clear whether you are asking about methodology because this is taking a massive amount of time, or whether you are asking about what you are currently doing.

If performance is a problem, you might be able to spin of each separate operation on their individual thread-pool-thread using `Task.Factory.StartNew`/`Task.Run` but depending on the machine architecture this may provide no speed up what-so-ever.

What you currently have should not lock the UI and if the performance is reasonable to you, I don't see that there is any real need to optimise what you are doing apart from renaming your async method to in clude an `Async` suffix [pretty minor stuff]

```
public async Task<IGroupedParts> GroupPartsAsync(GroupOption option){ ... }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, sounds good to me, because if I wrapped each call I would generate a bunch of code under to covers that would most likely make it slower. I just like to ask for things that I am getting a feel for. Thanks for the help.